# How do I combine ListView with react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have a listview with lot of items.I want to do is touching item and then jump to another page.
My question is how to pass the `navigator={this.props.navigator}` to the `renderRow`?

Thank you!

This is my `listview`:

```
  return (
      <ListView
        style={ styles.listView }
        dataSource={ this.state.dataSource }
        renderRow={ this.renderRow }} />
      );
```

This is my `renderRow`:

```
renderRow(event: Object) {
    return (

      <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Browser', {
                                          link: event.ItemName,
                                        }) }>
        <View style={ styles.row }>
          <Text style={ styles.textContainer }>
            <Text style={ styles.title }>
              { event.ItemName }
            </Text>
            <Text style={ styles.type }>
              { event.BTContent }
            </Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={ styles.cellBorder }></View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    )
  }
```

Comment: Are you using functional or class components? Are you getting any errors? Are you using `react-navigation` or `react-native-navigation` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListView is deprecated, use FlatList instead. If the renderRow function is in the same class that is used as a screen in react navigation you have access to the navigation prop inside the method and don't have to pass anything. If not please post the full relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like how you should be doing it to me. Regardless of if you're using a functional or class component, the component's props would contain `navigation`. You don't need to pass anything to `renderRow`.

sidenote: `ListView` is deprecated. Use `FlatList` or `SectionList` depending on your use case. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/03/13/better-list-views